# How to run python scripts against selenium grid

Tags: selenium-grid

I am able to run python scripts throgh selenium rc.
I dont know to run these scripts in selenium grid.I am not able to get the correct answer from anywhere.is it possible to run python scripts from selenium eclipse. 
Please anyone provide me the solution as soon as possible.
Thx.

Comment: You need to give more details on your scenario to get it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

first of all you have to install selenium with this code:

```
pip install -U selenium
```

Alternately, you can download the source distribution from [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) (e.g. selenium-2.53.1.tar.gz), unarchive it, and run:

```
python setup.py install
```

both of the methods described above install selenium as a system-wide package That will require administrative/root access to there machine. You may consider using a virtualenv to create isolated Python environments instead.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking a lot of things that don't really make sense.  E.g., there is no such thing as "selenium eclipse."  Anyway, I'll try to answer the best I can.

Your Python scripts should have the client connect to the Selenium Grid Hub instead of a specific RC Server.  The hub is then responsible for dispatching the request to any registered nodes in the grid.  There is nothing Python-specific involved with grid.